# Doesn't create a channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to use !test epicchannel (epicchannel being the name of the channel , for example if I want to use !test infinite , it will create a channel named testing-infinite ) but it doesn't work. it just makes a channel named testing-test

I've tried using message.content.startsWith, but if I do that, nothing happens.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!';

client.on("message", async message => {


    if(message.content.startsWith === '!test') {
        if(message.author.id === '560761436058550273') {
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

        message.guild.createChannel(`testing-${args}`).then(channel => {    
            channel.setTopic(`Today we will test: ${args}`)
        })
        }else{  
            if(!message.author.id === '560761436058550273') {   
                return;
            }
        }


}
});
client.login('login is here');
```

No errors, I just want it to use !test infinite to create a channel named testing-infinite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
```

to

```
const [_, args] = message.content.trim().split(' ')
```

That way we split the message by spaces after trimming it, and we actually save the second part in `args` variable by doing some array [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: it makes a channel named "testing-undefined"

Comment: Can you log `message.content` and tell us its value?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do `console.log(message.content)` just before creating your args variable and tell us what does that log in your console :)

Comment: It logs "!test" , but if I do "!test epic" it doesnt log anything

Comment: Mmmm i think you also have a typo, try changing `message.content.startsWith === '!test'` to `message.content.startsWith('!test')`

Comment: Haha, no problem! Sorry i didn't see that before :P

Answer (score 0):

`args` is an array, just join `testing-` and `args[1]` to get the name you want:

```
rodrigo:~:node
> const prefix = '!';
undefined
> var message = { content:'!test epicchannel'}
undefined
> message
{ content: '!test epicchannel' }
> const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
undefined
> args
[ 'test', 'epicchannel' ]
> var channelName = `testing-${args[1]}`;
undefined
> channelName
'testing-epicchannel'
```